# Reducing Python zip size to use with AWS Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/) blog post to create a runtime environment using Docker for use with AWS Lambda. I'm creating a layer for using with Python 3.8:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

And then archiving the layer as zip: `zip -9 -r mylayer.zip python`

All standard so far. The problem arises in the `.zip` size, which is > 250mb and so creates the following error in Lambda: `Failed to create layer version: Unzipped size must be smaller than 262144000 bytes`.

Here's my `requirements.txt`:

```
s3fs
scrapy
pandas
requests
```

I'm including `s3fs` since I get the following error when trying to save a parquet file to an S3 bucket using pandas: `[ERROR] ImportError: Install s3fs to access S3`. This problem is that including `s3fs` massively increases the layer size. Without `s3fs` the layer is < 200mb unzipped.

My most direct question would be: **How can I reduce the layer size to < 250mb while still using Docker and keeping `s3fs` in my `requirements.txt`?** I can't explain the 50mb+ difference, especially since `s3fs` < 100kb on [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/s3fs/#files).

Finally, for those questioning my use of Lambda with Scrapy: my scraper is trivial, and spinning up an EC2 instance would be overkill.

Comment: If you have lots of dependencies, container lambdas are the solution. You have 10GB for your dependencies.

Comment: appreciate the suggestion @Marcin - will take a look. for the time being, using Python 3.6 rather than 3.8 sufficiently decreased the layer size

Comment: Sure. Give me few minutes.

Comment: @mmz take a look at my answer for some suggestions that might help you further reduce size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key idea behind shrinking your layers is to identify what `pip` installs and what you can get rid off, usually manually.

In your case, since you are only slightly above the limit, I would get rid off `pandas/tests`. So before you create your zip layer, you can run the following in the layer's folder (`mylayer` from your past question):

```
rm -rvf python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/tests
```

This should trim your layer below the 262MB limit after unpacking. In my test it is now **244MB**.

Alternatively, you can go over `python` folder manually, and start removing any other tests, documentations, examples, etc, that are not needed.

Comment: @mmz No problem. Glad could help:-)

Answer (score 5):

> I can't explain the 50mb+ difference, especially since s3fs < 100kb on PyPi.

That's simple enough to explain. As expected, `s3fs` has [internal dependencies](https://github.com/dask/s3fs/blob/main/requirements.txt#L1) on AWS libraries (`botocore` in this case). The good news is that `boto3` is already included in AWS lambda (see [this link](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/4a052f39490fae00e0c3#file-all_aws_lambda_modules_python3-7-txt) for which libraries are available in lambda) therefore you can exclude `botocore` from your zipped dependencies and save **up to ~50MB in total size**.

See the above link for more info. The libraries you can safely remove from your zipped artifact file and still be able to run the code on an AWS lambda function running Python 3.8:

- boto3
- botocore
- docutils
- jmespath
- pip
- python-dateutil (generates the `dateutil` package)
- s3transfer
- setuptools
- six (generates `six.py`)
- urllib3 (if needed, bundled dependencies like `chardet` could also be removed)

You can also use a bash script to recursively get rid of the following (junk) directories that you don't need:

- `__pycache__`
- `*.dist-info` (example: *certifi-2021.5.30.dist-info*)
- `tests` - Only *possibly*, but I can't confirm. If you do choose to recursively get rid of all `tests` folders, first check if anything breaks on lambda, since in rare cases such a package could be imported in code.

---

Do all this and you should easily save **around ~60MB in zipped artifact size.**

Comment: Do you have a reference for those libraries already included in AWS Lambda?

Comment: Yes, it should be included in the link in the answer. But anyways, here is the reference: https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/4a052f39490fae00e0c3#file-all_aws_lambda_modules_python3-7-txt

Comment: For libraries in the Python 3.8 runtime, you can just do a text search for '3.8' and you should find a post that lists the 3.8 specific libraries.

Comment: What about binary Wheel packages - don't they "install" files to `*.dist-info`?

Comment: @FredrikWendt hmm, I'm not sure actually. do you have an example of a package that installs files to a `*.dist-info` folder?